# Definespresentationcontext causes content shift under searcher?

Tags: swift, xcode9

I'm using Swift 4 with xcode 9.1. This question is somewhat confusing, so I've included images to hopefully help out.

Here is my setup:
[image]

When I navigate from VC1 to subVC1, then tab over to VC2 and into subVC2, then tab back to subVC1, everything works perfectly.

When I do the above after having typed something into the search bar in VC1, I get view A (below, black screen).

When I set `definesPresentationContext = true` for VC1, this solves the black screen problem but creates a new problem. Normally when you segue back from subCV1 to VC1 with something typed in the searcher, it looks like view B (below, middle panel). With `definesPresentationContext = true`, VC1 ends up looking like view C (below, right panel) after segueing back from subVC1. Everything is shifted up and hidden by the searchbar.

This also happens for the unnamed VC above that also navigates to subVC1.

How might I figure out why the content is being shifted up and how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing out quite a lot of solutions (setting content y position, confirming proper constraints), I found the issue.

Whereas previously, my setup necessitated unchecking **Extend edges under top bars**, the new setup requires that it be checked. See new working setup below, which fixes all visual glitches in my original question. Hope this helps someone!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post several times while investigating a similar problem, so I wanted to post my findings here.

My `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` was "popping" onto the top of my search results - located in a `UITableView` - a split second after navigating back from a `ViewController` to my `UISearchController`.

"Under top bars" was checked in my Storyboard file as above, but I had declared `definesPresentationContext` in my code.

I found out that I needed to add an additional line so that the header wouldn't jump anymore:

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
definesPresentationContext = true
```

It prevented both the "black screen" issue *and* the content shifting problem.

Comment: The answer marked correct didn't work for me, but this did. Every time I popped back to the VC with my search bar my views would extend behind the large nav bars which caused my empty collection view background image to be partially hidden.